# finding concept by using word similarity

Tags: nlp

I have given word by word similarity matrix and I want to form a concept as a weighted sum of words. What is the right approach for this problem. Is latent semantic analysis useful here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ConceptNet](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu).
LSA (latent semantic analysis) is ok when you dont know care what the concepts are as long as intimately related words are clustered together into a concept. 
Explicit Semantic Analysis could be more useful, but you already have a similarity matrix.
I think you need to first identify a concept dictionary that you want to represent.